# I've an error but I don't find the problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want execute this command, but when I execute this command, I've this error message : 
Error code :

```
    (node:8616) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 400 Bad Request
    at C:\Users\Eleve\Desktop\FA Bot\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:195:23
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:8616) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:8616) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections 
that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is the code :

```
    const Discord = require("discord.js")
const botconfig = require("../botconfig.json");
const colours = require("../colours.json");
const prefix = botconfig.prefix
const webhook = require("webhook-discord")

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

const Hook = new webhook.Webhook("https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/689803124957118476/xiz3sE3dhQhjW7CoJrTIVB60LCckSHYm_0X9OwlGEQwDnmKYHzFuvekImwxjSaOuhoN-")
const msg = new webhook.MessageBuilder()
                .setName(message.author.username)
                .setColor("RANDOM")
                .setText("Test")
                .setTime();

Hook.send(msg)

}

module.exports.config = {
    name: "webhook",
    aliases: ["wh"],
    usage: "!usage",
    description: "",
    accessableby: "Membres"
}
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: You are getting an HTTP error `400 Bad Request` which mean that your request is not correct. discord-webhook has last been updated 6 months ago, so I guess there has been a breaking change in the Discord API. I suggest you use the discord.js webhooks which work fine by themselves

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The error itself has already told you. The reason of having the error is due to ***Unhandled promise rejection***.

Reasons:

```
1. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or
2. by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().
```

It means you can deal with the problem by:

```
1. You can move you async function into a try and catch block in order to catch the error when the function has failed 
2. You can add a .catch() chain function as node suggested.
```

Error msg usually got the answer, learning how to read them is very important. I am still learning how to read it. Hope it helps.

Materials:

1. Error handling with Async/Await in JS by Ian Segers, [link](https://itnext.io/error-handling-with-async-await-in-js-26c3f20bc06a)

Comment: It's not as clear as just reading the error message.  Yes it provides clues where to look, but simply catching the error rather than finding the reason the error is being thrown is not always the solution.  More often than not, we want the errors so we know something is wrong with our code.

Comment: You explained the shallow problem, not the cause. The real issue here is a malformed request to the Discord webhook endpoint.